# Rails 4: passing model params from parent show view to model new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

In my Rails 4 app, I have two models:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

These models use shallow routes:

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :posts, shallow: true 
end
```

The post model has a `datetime` `:date` custom attribute.

In my calendar controller, in addition to the default actions, I also have a custom `Calendars#Calendar_view` action, used as an alternative to the regular `Calendars#Show` action.

On both of these views, we list all the posts that belong to the current calendar:

```
def show
  @posts = @calendar.posts
end

def calendar_view
  @posts = @calendar.posts
end
```

Users are allowed to create new posts from one `Posts#New` view in the app, but they can access this view from several places in the app.

For instance, I have a *Create new post* button in the header of `Calendars#show`, another one in the header of `Calendars#Calendar_view`, etc.

In addition, in the `Calendars#Calendar_view` view, which uses the `simple_calendar` gem to display the posts inside a calendar, I have the following code:

```
<%= month_calendar events: @posts do |date,posts| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, data: {date: date, calendar_id: @calendar.id} do %>
    <%= date.strftime('%e') %> <span id="calendar_view_plus_sign"><%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>'.html_safe, new_calendar_post_path(@calendar) %></span>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="single_event">
        <%= link_to post.subject, post_path(post) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which gives the following view, with green "plus" signs appearing in each calendar cell on hover:

[image]

—————

***Note***: it seems the green "plus" signs do not appear on the gif above, but as you can see at the left bottom of the image (towards the end of the loop), the path to post/new appears.

—————

What I am trying to accomplish now, is to grab a date from the cell where the user clicks on the green button, and pass it to the `Posts#New` form.

Ideally then, in the `Posts#New` form, the `datetime_select` field would be populated with the `date` that we grabbed in the Calendars#Calendar_view and the current `time`.

(We do not need any custom `time` to be passed to the form, just the current `time`, as it is the case now).

But I don't want any date to be passed to the `Posts#New` form when users access the form from another link in the app (see above for the list of all links available in the app to `Posts#New` form).

How can I achieve this?

—————

**UPDATE**: I have tried to update the link on the green "plus" signs in the `Calendars#Calendar_view` view as follows:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>'.html_safe, new_calendar_post_path(@calendar, date: date) %>
```

This kind of work, since the new generated link looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/calendars/1/posts/new?date=2016-01-08
```

However, in the `Posts#New` form, the correct date does not appear in the datetime select field, which is still set to the default current date and time.

Any idea how to make the form display the date we pass through the URL?

—————

**UPDATE 2**: I believe the challenge now is to grab the :date param in the `Posts#New` action.

I tried this:

```
@post.date = post_params[:date] unless post_params[:date].empty?
```

But it generates the followings error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PostsController#new
param is missing or the value is empty: post
```

I also tried:

```
date = params[:date] unless params[:date].empty?
```

and

```
@post.date = params[:date] unless params[:date].empty?
```

But with this code, the form still does not grab the correct date.

Any idea about how to make this work?